# Change date column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working on a stock market analysis where I look at past Balance Sheets and income statements, and want to change the date column which saves them as a string of the form "2021-09-30" into datetimes. I am trying to use pd.to_datetime but it is giving me an error.

When I run

```
df['datekey'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datekey'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I get

> "ValueError: time data "2021-09-30" doesn't match format specified"

when it should (if I am doing this correctly).

This column doesn't have a time value in it. It is just (for all dates) "2021-09-30".

Comment: Can you include the output of `df['datekey'].head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: Also when I ran the string that was rejected and my format by copy and pasting both on datetime.datetime.strptime() I had no error and it converted it correctly

Comment: The output of df['datekey'].head(10).to_dict()
{0: '"2021-09-30"', 1: '"2021-06-30"', 2: '"2021-03-31"', 3: '"2020-12-31"', 4: '"2020-09-3
0"', 5: '"2020-06-30"', 6: '"2020-03-31"', 7: '"2019-12-31"', 8: '"2019-09-30"', 9: '"2019-
06-30"'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra quotes and spaces in your data. Try:

```
df["datekey"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datekey"].str.replace(" ","").str.strip('"'), format="%Y-%m-%d")

>>> df["datekey"] 
0   2021-09-30
1   2021-06-30
2   2021-03-31
3   2020-12-31
4   2020-09-30
5   2020-06-30
6   2020-03-31
7   2019-12-31
8   2019-09-30
9   2019-06-30
Name: datekey, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the value itself is enclosed by double quotes, you need to include quotes as well in your formats:

```py
df['datekey'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datekey'], format='"%Y-%m-%d"')
```

Alternatively, you can strip off the quotes before converting to datetime, this is useful if some values are not enclosed by double quotes:

```py
df['datekey'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datekey'].str.strip('"'), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```